# Quitar comillas dobles(") a archivo .csv generado con la función fputcsv de php

Tags: php

estoy usando la función fputcsv de php para generar un archivo .csv, pero necesito que los nombres del archivo de salida no estén encerrados por comillas dobles(") he usado str_replace(""", '', $data['nombre]) pero no me funciona agradezco alguna ayuda o sugerencia.

```
fputcsv($output, array(
  $data['id'],
  $data['nombre']
),';');

ARCHIVO DE SALIDA:

ID;NOMBRE
1;"Juan perez"
2;"Lina Diaz"
3;"Andres Lopez"
```

Comment: Intenta con comillas simples `str_replace('"',"",$data['nombre'])`

Comment: Esto debería producirte un contenido sin comillas: `fputcsv($output, array($data['id'],$data['nombre]),';',chr(0));`

Comment: tu código tiene un error de sintaxis seguro que corre???  `$data['nombre]` debería ser  `$data['nombre']`

Comment: ya corregí el error de sintaxis

Answer (score 1):

Usando `fputcsv` se están agregando las comillas dobles, usa el parámetro "enclosure" definiendo como valor null (`chr(0)`) para que no se muestre las comillas doble ya que el carácter por defecto es precisamente `"` :

```
fputcsv($output, array(
  $data['id'],
  $data['nombre']
),';', chr(0));
```